# Extracting similar items from a website with beautiful soup

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I`m trying to scrape a website rating. I want to get each individual rating and it´s particular date. However, I only get one result in my list, although there should be several.
Am I doing something wrong in the for loop?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import time

url = "https://www.kununu.com/de/heidelpay/kommentare"

while url != " ":
    print(url)
    time.sleep(15)
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    print(r.status_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    
    #print(soup.prettify())

#Get overall score of the company
score_avg = soup.find("span", class_="index__aggregationValue__32exy").text
print(score_avg)

#get individuel scores and dates of the company
rating_list = []

for box in soup.find_all(".index__rating__3nC2L"):
    score_ind = box.select(".index__score__16yy9").text
    date = select(".index__date__eIOxr").text
    rating = [score_ind, date]

rating_list.append(rating)

print(rating_list)
```

> 

3,3
[['5,0', 'Januar 2017']]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't appending the rating to the rating_list until the last loop is done. Is the printed rating perchance the very last one?

Add the `append` to your loop, like so:

```
for box in soup.find_all(".index__rating__3nC2L"):
    score_ind = box.select(".index__score__16yy9").text
    date = select(".index__date__eIOxr").text
    rating = [score_ind, date]
    rating_list.append(rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that you're just appending the last `rating` value in     `rating_list.append(rating)` because it's out of the foor loop, so what you have to do is this:

```
for box in soup.find_all(".index__rating__3nC2L"):
    score_ind = box.select(".index__score__16yy9").text
    date = select(".index__date__eIOxr").text
    rating = [score_ind, date]
    rating_list.append(rating)
```

Like this way you're gonna append each `rating` value in each iteration of the `for`loop. Hope this can help you

Comment: Hi Brad , thank you very much for the reply. If I do that, I only get the following result:
`
3,3
[]`

Comment: It should work, but it seems there is a logic mistake with your scraper and it's not related with the `loop`